# Ruby on Rails each iteration error when one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration, each

I am stuck on what seems should have a very simple solution, but I can not find anything that will work!  I am iterating results from a table on the index page (which returns a list of states).  This works without any problems when multiple records are returned.  However, when a single record is returned, I get an error: undefined method 'each' for #

I know it is causing the error when only one record is returned, but I can not find any documentation on how to handle this, especially in the case that 1 or 0 records could be returned.

Code in controller:

```
@states = State.find(params[:id])
```

Code in index page:

```
<ul>
  <% @states.each do |state| %>
    <li>
      <%= state.state_name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple states with the same id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using `find`, when you send multiple ids in the params, multiple records are matched; when you send a single id, a single instance is returned.

To ensure that each time, you get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that you can call `each` on, change your controller code to the following:

```
@states = State.where(id: params[:id]) # index action
```

You mentioned that it is the `index` view, so the above change should solve your problem.

If it's the `show` view, then you need to stick with `find` and change your view to display only one `state`.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked perfectly, and was exactly what I was trying to do!  I'm just starting to learn RoR and have only seen find being used in the tutorials.  This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if it responds to .each, which is the prime given for knowing if something implements the ***enumerable*** module.

```
if @states.respond_to?(:each)
  # iteration goes here
else
  # single handling goes here
```

Ofcourse you can also use the .where option in your query which returns always a collection

```
@states = State.where(id: params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1:-

When record is queried in controller as:

```
@states = State.find(params[:id])
```

Then in view it should be like that:

```
<p><%= @states.state_name %></p>
```

Scenario 2:-

When  record is queried in controller as:

```
@states = State.all
```

Then in view it should be like that:

```
<ul>
  <% @states.each do |state| %>
    <li>
      <%= state.state_name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**Note**:- In first scenario it is only one object but in second scenario it is a collection of object or a array of object. And only array are iterated.